# User database using Steam OpenID

Tags: php, mysql, openid

I'm trying to create a user management system using steam openid, but I'm not sure what the table should look like. I'm used to having the basic user table containing the usual userid, username and password. Then using cookies confirming if the user is logged in. I'm not entirely sure on how to do this using steamopenID though.

I've completed the login and verification but have not yet figured out to have a working database with it. After successful login it returns the Users SteamID. What can I do with this to create a safe user system?

I was thinking of redirecting the user to a new page where they can register a username if the steamid itself doesnt exist, but how do I verify if a user is logged in our not using only the steamid?

Comment: Openid allows to request user-data like the name of the user and it's email. Probably get comfortable with what it is first: http://openid.net/add-openid/

Comment: Steam OpenID is not really openid, they say it is but pretty much all it returns is the users steamid.

Comment: Create an entry in your users profile table that contains the steamid. Users with steamid can login via steam then. See my answer that has some shema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two authentication providers, one from your own site or alternatively, one from steam. For the accounts you accept openid auths, you need to store their openid authentifications next to them, so when somebody logs into your site via an openid provider you find out which actual user of your site this is.

You session always is connected to your site's user-id:

```
    [login] 
       |
[authentication]
       |
       \-----+--> [openid auth] ---> [steam id] --\
             |                                    |
             \--> [site user auth] ------> [site user id]
                                                  |
                                              [session]
```

Comment: And to verify the user is logged in I check if the steam id exists in the users session?

Comment: No, the session knows which user it represents, so to verify if the user is logged in you look into the session and obtain the user from it. Then you can lookup in the database if a steamid is associated with the user.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, it is like any other login system.

You're just not responsible for the login stuff. But yes, just as you say. When you have verified the ID, check if the ID exists in your own users database, and if it doesn't, work with that and redirect them to a "Create Profile" login.

Comment: But how do I verify if a user is logged in? If I store the userid in a cookie then you could easily spoof it and log in as another user.

Comment: You should use sessions to keep the user logged in, just like any other membership website.